# Convert a Python List to an Array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm trying to convert a list to a numpy array. My list's length is 64, each element of the list is an numpy array(8 x 8).  My output should be a numpy array of (8,8,1,64). How can I convert list to numpy array.

```
type(dct)
>>>list

len(dct)
>>>64

type(dct[0])
>>>numpy.ndarray

dct[0].shape
>>>(8,8)
```

Comment: Do all the arrays have the same shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call the [**`numpy.array`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) constructor:

```
from numpy import array

the_array = array(dct)
```

But this only works if *all* the elements of the list have the same shape (if not, we still can use an `array(..)`, but then we get a 1D array of objects.

For example:

```
>>> dct = [array([1, 4, 2, 5]), array([1, 3, 0, 2])]
>>> array(dct)
array([[1, 4, 2, 5],
       [1, 3, 0, 2]])

In case the elements have a different shape:

>>> dct = [array([1, 4, 2, 5]), array([1, 3, 0])]
>>> array(dct)
array([array([1, 4, 2, 5]), array([1, 3, 0])], dtype=object)
```